# What to do I want to access all [i] in every tuple inside a list or a dictionary (python)?

Tags: python, spyder

Let's say I have a dictionary called 'testdic' that looks like this.

```
testdic = {
    [
        ( ('Jane','Sophomore','Science'), (4.0,3.5,3.2) ),
        ( ('Kim','Junior','Business'), (3.2,2.8,4.0) ),
        ( ('Jack','Senior','Music'), (3.0,4.0,3.0) )
    ]
}
```

And I need to pull all the [2] of the key together to get a list that look like 'Science','Business','Music'. How would I do that?

I know that I should turn testdic into a list. So I wrote `test.list = list(testdic.keys())`. But then what?

I actually need to write this into a function that would take two variables; the name of the dictionary, and the index. For example, if I want to pull the names into a list. I should be able to write `list(functionname(testdic,0))`

I did some google search and found a code below.

```
def select(dic, ind):
    if(type(dic) is dict):
        if (ind == 0):
            return dic.key()
        elif(ind == 1):
            return dic.values()
        else: 
            dic=list(dic)
            return [i[ind] for i in dic]
```

It executed. But when I tried `list(select(testdic,keys(),2))`, nothing comes up.

Any tips, suggestion would be helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: What you have inside is not a dict but a set

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a list of unhashable type.

To solve this error, ensure you only assign a hashable object, such as a string or a tuple, as a key for a dictionary.

```
testdic = {(('Jane','Sophomore','Science'), (4.0,3.5,3.2)),

(('Kim','Junior','Business'), (3.2,2.8,4.0)),

(('Jack','Senior','Music'), (3.0,4.0,3.0))}
```

So you have to write (for 'Science','Business','Music')

```
for value in testdic:
   print(value[0][2])
```